# Add one every time click ADD button

Tags: javascript, jquery

NEED HELP!
How to add one every time I click "Add" button?

The number will increase every time I click.

It's start from 0, after I click it's will plus 1 become 1, then 2 and etc.

HTML:

```
<div id="add_form">

    <div class="form-field">

        <div class="field">

            <div class="no">0</div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<a href="#" id="add_field" class="btn btn-default">Add </a>
<p><br /></p>
```

JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var MaxInputs       = 8;
    var InputsWrapper   = $("#add_form");
    var AddButton       = $("#add_field");

    var x = InputsWrapper.length;
    var FieldCount=1;

    $(AddButton).click(function (e) {

        if(x <= MaxInputs) {

            FieldCount++;

            $(InputsWrapper).append('<div class="field"><div class="no">1</div></div>');
            x++;

        }

        return false;

    });

});
```

My JQuery quite poor, need some help from you guys.

Also, here is the jsfiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/fzs77/

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `1` hardcoded, so it can't change. Do it like this:

```
$(InputsWrapper).append('<div class="field"><div class="no">' + x + '</div></div>');
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xSRxQ/) with working demo.

Answer (score 2):

You have to out the variable that holds the number inside of the html that you append. Also move the increscent of the  `FieldCount` variable to below the append function call to render the correct result.
Like so:

```
$(AddButton).click(function (e) {

    if(x <= MaxInputs) {

        $(InputsWrapper).append('<div class="field"><div class="no">' + FieldCount + '</div></div>');
        x++;
        FieldCount++;

    }

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fzs77/7/

```
<div id="add_form">


<div class="form-field">

        <div class="field">

            <div class="no">0</div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<a href="#" id="add_field" class="btn btn-default">Add </a>
<p><br /></p>
```

**JS file**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var MaxInputs       = 8;
    var InputsWrapper   = $("#add_form");
    var AddButton       = $("#add_field");

    var x = InputsWrapper.length;
    var FieldCount=0;

    $(AddButton).click(function (e) {

        if(x <= MaxInputs) {

            FieldCount++;



   $(InputsWrapper).append('<div class="field"><div class="no">' + FieldCount + '</div></div>');



        }

        return false;

    });

});
```

Comment: sorry. it was by mistake. Can't revoke it untill the answer is edited.
Now Solved. accept my +1 as an apology.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this if you want to increment it while on the same line.**

http://jsfiddle.net/sdMCH/

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#add_field').click(function (e) {
            var x=$(".no");            
            x[0].innerHTML = (parseInt(x[0].innerHTML,10)+1);
        }
    );
});
```